# Why does the SSIS package fail when deployed to Integration Services Catalogs but runs fine on Visual studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence, dataflowtask

I have a very simple SSIS package that takes data form an Excel sheet and dumps into a table. No Data conversion, a straight import. The package runs perfectly on Visual Studio but when deployed, I get the errors you see in the attached picture.

I also changed the project properties -> Debugging -> Run 64 bit runtime to False and re-deployed the package but the errors persist.

[image: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode]

Comment: My guess is that you don't have the driver installed in your SSIS server.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a driver issue. If this is a one time thing, I would suggest converting the excel file into a csv and then importing. The challenges are lesser with csv.

Comment: On the ssis server, if you are running it as a job, on the SQL Agent job configuration screen. You'll find it on the "Execution options" tab, check the option "use 32 bit runtime".

Comment: The first thing I'd focus on is `The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB 4.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode`. As the others have said, retry in 32 bit mode. The default is 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that the OLE DB provider isn't installed. The 32 bit and 64 bit providers are separate installations. Might as well make sure both are installed.